# Python Django What is the pythonic way to import modules

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, import

I am using Django, Django rest_framework to build my apis. My directory structure looks like this

```
|-user_directory\
  |-__init__.py
  |-models\
    |-__init__.py
    |-contact.py
  |-views\
    |-__init__.py
    |-contact.py
|-myproject
```

When I am writing my views there are a lot of imports, so I moved them to my `__init__.py.` Currently my imports looks like this

File `user_directory/__init__.py`

```
import logging, re, pdb
logger = logging.getLogger("user_directory")
```

File `user_directory/views/__init__.py`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework import status as rest_status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from lib.request_utils import validate_request, CustomTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from user_directory import *
```

File `user_directory/views/contact.py`

```
from user_directory.views import *
from user_directory.models.contact import Contact
```

Now I read at many places doing something like this `from package import *` is considered a bad practice in python. I am writing all the common imports in `views/__init__.py` to not repeat the code.

Is this way correct ? What is the most pythonic way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

It's really opinion-based question, so here is my opinion.

Using `from package import *` syntax is horrible idea almost always. The first problem is that you have no idea from where the variable came from: was it defined in imported file, was it imported in that file from another file. It's really hard to manage, when your project grows.

Your IDE/linter has no idea from where this variable came either. So it can't check for undeclared variables, can't properly find usages and your can't use Refactor -> Rename function (which is the most painful).

I would suggest to import everything by it's exact name in every file. And do not consider it a code duplication.

The two things I would improve in your imports are:

1. Put every root package import on separate line:

   ```
   import logging
   import re
   import pdb
   ```
2. Write imports in the following order (standard library package, third-party packages and imports from your package), separate them by empty line and order groups alphabetically. It makes it much easier to read:

   ```
   from django.http import JsonResponse
   from rest_framework import status as rest_status
   from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
   from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
   from rest_framework.response import Response

   from lib.request_utils import validate_request, CustomTokenAuthentication
   ```